# Adding tap behavior to Xamarin label

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

I have several labels with texts on a page. When I tap on a label, I am displaying a separate page, with a specific title, to edit the tapped label contents.

I used `Label.GestureRecognizers` and invoked different commands, associated with every label.

I would like to unify this approach, remove all these specific commands and have an universal behavior, attached to a label, page title will be passed as a parameter to this behavior.

And when I tap/click on this label, this behavior should do something I want.

My behavior class looks like that:

```
public class EditTextBehavior : Behavior<Label>
{
    public string PageTitle { get; set; }
    
    protected override void OnAttachedTo(Label bindable)
    {
        base.OnAttachedTo(bindable);

        // I would like to bind tap/click event to label here ('bindable' method parameter)
        // but label does not have onClick or onTap events 
        // Focused event do not work as expected.

    }

    protected override void OnDetachingFrom(Label bindable)
    {
        base.OnDetachingFrom(bindable);
        // Performing cleanup here
    }
}
```

And I use it in xaml-page, into label element, like this:

```
  <Label.Behaviors>
      <behaviors:EditTextBehavior PageTitle="Some title"/>
  </Label.Behaviors>
```

My question: into `OnAttachedTo()` method of behavior class I would like to attach a handler to the label click/tap event, to process this click/tap event and do something.

How can I do that?

Having a command instead of behavior is not convenient, because I have many parameters for every label.

Comment: How about creating a Custom Control inheriting a Label. Then add Bindeable property to that control. Maybe one parameter = one Bindeable property.

Comment: Use this
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/xamarin-forms-eventtocommand-behavior-in-mvvm-viewmodel/
and redirect your tap along with all the parameters to your view model

Comment: @ShubhamTyagi thank you. I have `event-to- command behavior` in my code, in this case the xaml code will look like I use `Label.GestureRecognizers` with the Command inside. It does not help, because Command allows only one parameter, and this parameter should be a string. Otherwise, if this parameter is not a string, and refers to a object in view model, the command don't executes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what do you mean by many parameters. like one you mention is page title , can you give more example.
Is this what you want
Custom Label with bindable properties.

```
<MyCustomLabel x:Name="myLabel1" PageTitle="My Title" Param2="second Param" Param3="3" ...>
   <MyCustomLabel.GestureRecognizer>
     <TapGestureRecognizer Command={Binding TapCommand} CommandParameter={x:Reference myLabel1}/>
   </MyCustomLabel.GestureRecognizer>
</MyCustomLabel>
```

ViewModel

```
public ICommand TapCommand{get;set;}
...
TapCommand = new Command<object>(OnLabelTapped)
...
private void OnLabelTapped(object obj)
{
  if(obj is MyCustomLabel myLabel)
  {
     string title = mylabel.PageTitle;
     int value = myLabel.Param3;
     ...
  }
}
```